# Session variable returning null ...after couple of postbacks..though user session is valid

Tags: .net

I have logged in to the application (In development Environment) with my userid and pswd...
I am using Session variables in the application..in order to access some values across different pages. Though my session didnt time out, my session variables are becoming null after a while...Can some one please help me with this..

Thanks,

Comment: Have you set any custom session timeouts in app? Small code snippet on how you are storing values into session variables and retrieving it would help

Comment: There are no custom session time outs set..
I am assigning values to the session variables as below
session["TotalRows"] = RowsCount;
and retreiving the values using
int RowCount;//Variable declared in another page
RowCount = session["TotalRows"];

Answer (score 1):

I would add handlers in your Global.asax.  Log anytime any of the Application_Start, Application_End, Session_Start, and Session_End are called.

The Session_End method should be called any time a session ends, and may give you a clue as to why your session variables are disappearing.  This only works when the session is persisted InProc mode though.

Note that if your application recycles in IIS, then all of the session data will be lost as well, so that is why I would recommend logging at all points in the Application and Session startup / teardown.